# How do I apply a function to each subgroup of a table in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find the minimum value of a column in a certain date range of a table.

so lets say I have a table like the following,

```
Date  | Value
---------------
01-26 | 2
01-26 | 1
01-27 | 2
01-27 | 4
01-28 | 3
01-28 | 5
```

How can I apply the MIN() function to the subgroup of the Value column so that the result might be

```
Date | MIN(Value)
---------------
01-26 | 1
01-27 | 2
01-28 | 3
```

I thought about `GROUP BY` .. or  such but couldn't figure out how to get the results into a table.
Using `UNION` and `JOIN` isn't quite scalable because the query could be using a date range of a month

Comment: you know you have to use `min` and `group by`. why don't you try it first?

Comment: you are absolutely right.. I was overthinking the sql statement and just dismissed things.. I should've just tried :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by should work:

```
Select date, min( value ) 
From table1
Group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too simple, but seems like this would work

```
Select Min(col1), datecol from yourtable group by datecol;
```

HTH

Comment: if you have a date field with a full date, and you have to actually produce a datepart, just group by your datepart function (depending on what DB you're using)